# Rename Azure DevOps hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We recently switched our Azure DevOps organization from the free Hosted Agent offering to two paid hosted agents. When the second hosted agent was added, it was automatically named "Azure Pipelines 2" which is a fine enough name. The issue is that the original agent seems to be named "Hosted Agent" and I can't for the life of me find a way to rename it. It would be great if it could just be renamed to "Azure Pipelines 1". Is it possible to rename a hosted agent? If so, how does one do this as I have looked in Organization Settings at the Agent Pools option and do not see any way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rename Azure DevOps hosted Agent

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently not supported in Azure Devops. Hosted agent name cannot be modified.

Currently only private agent name can be renamed, run `config.cmd remove` first, that will take care of remove the windows service and also remove the agent from your azure devops , then run `config.cmd` again  to re-config in order to change the agent name, the agent name is a primary key in the backend.

So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/945069/rename-azure-devops-hosted-agent.html) in DC forum for you . You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there.The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Anyone interested in this can vote for it and track it.